# Working out the value of this two-player game

Tags: game-theory

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now in the solution, I understand how the game tree has been constructed but that's about it. Once the game tree has been constructed I don't understand **at all** how we work backwards from the terminal vertices to arrive at the value of 0 for the game. Shouldn't the value of the game be 1 as then P1 would receive the max payoff from P2, but then I arrived at this answer just by looking at all the payoff values in which the value of 1 was the highest which is obviously not the right way to work out the value of the game. **But otherwise once the game tree has been constructed I don't even know how to begin finding out the value of the game and don't understand how we work backwards from each of the terminal vertices.**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Player $2$ minimises the payoff, and Player $1$ maximises it. Thus you can work backwards on the basis that each player will play accordingly. This yields the following payoffs:

\begin{array}{}
-14&&0&&1&&-9&&0\\
&-14&&0&&-9&&-9\\
&&0&&0&&-9\\
&&&0&&-9\\
&&\hphantom{-9}&\hphantom{-9}&0
\end{array}

The green path in your diagram shows the optimal moves, with Player $2$ being indifferent between the two moves on her first turn that both yield a payoff of $0$.